# Организации функции для передачи другой функции в качестве аргумента

Tags: c++

```
void MyFunc(float x)
{
    //......
}

void MyFunc2(int x)
{
    //......
}

void MyFunc3(float x, std::string str)
{
    //......
}

void Do(/*Функция в качестве параметра*/)
{
    // Выполнение этой функции
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Do(MyFunc, 1);
    Do(MyFunc, 1.f, "Str");

    return 0;
}
```

Помогите реализовать функцию `Do`. Мне нужно, чтобы я мог передать туда одну из функций, описанных выше и вызвать ее. Думаю, по коду все понятно :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так вас устроит?

```
template<typename Func, typename... Arg>
void Do(Func f, Arg... arg)
{
    f(arg...);
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Do(MyFunc2, 1);
    Do(MyFunc3, 1.f, "Str");
}
```

Или вы хотите вызывать именно `MyFunc`, чтоб она принимала несвойственные ей параметры?...

P.S. Более корректно, с учетом всяких возможных ссылок, семантики перемещения etc —

```
template<typename Func, typename... Arg>
auto Do(Func f, Arg&&... arg) -> decltype(f(std::forward<Arg>(arg)...))
{
    return f(std::forward<Arg>(arg)...);
}
```

Но самый простой метод — просто написать

```
#define Do std::invoke
```

поскольку "все <s>укра...</s> придумано до нас", и эта функциональность давно [входит в стандартную библиотеку](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke)...

Comment: Да, мне это нужно. А можно только это сделать в стиле С как-то?

Comment: Чтоб безопасно и без хакерства — писать три разные функции `Do` :)

Comment: Без `forward` совсем грустно. :(

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Дайте человеку для начала разобраться с этим. Если уж строка передается по значению... Впрочем, сейчас добавлю.