# C++ Как привязать любую функцию к классу?

Tags: c++, классы, указатели, шаблоны-с++, методы

Всем привет! Ситуация такая: есть класс, есть в нем какой-то метод, который должен принимать любое число параметров (разных) и есть функция, объявленная например глобально, как сделать так, чтобы при вызове этого метода класса вызывалась именно эта глобальная функция или же любая другая с параметрами, которые будут переданы методу класса, ее вызывающему?

Т.е. чтобы редактировать метод класса под каждую функцию не нужно было. Что-то пробовал с указателями на функцию, но ничего путного не придумал. Может можно как-то с шаблонами поиграться?
Предпочтительнее вариант без шаблонов (т.е. когда функция не будет инстанцирована много раз для каждой другой вызываемой функции)

Все это нужно для самодельного класса кнопки, у которой есть метод `activate( *something*)`, который вызывается при ее нажатии и должен вызвать любую функцию, принимающую *something* параметры. Как сделать такой метод и как хранить какую именно функцию он должен вызывать?

Comment: Вы не чего-то такого хотите? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1502759/195342

Comment: @Harry выглядит как то, что надо! Спасибо большое!

Comment: Ну вызывайте её в теле метода. В чём проблема?

Comment: Забыли KISS-принцип? Зачем сложно (т.е. передавать неизвесто сколько параметров), если можно  реализовать этот функционал в духе старого, проверенного поколениями успешной разработки [on_exit](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/on_exit.3.html)?

Answer (score 4):

Правильно так:

```
template <typename ...P>
decltype(auto) foo(P &&... params)
{
    return bar(std::forward<P>(params)...);
}
```

А совсем правильно так:

```
template <typename ...P>
auto foo(P &&... params)
noexcept(noexcept(bar(std::forward<P>(params)...)))
-> decltype(bar(std::forward<P>(params)...))
{
    return bar(std::forward<P>(params)...);
}
```

Comment: А зачем decltype к auto нужен? И можете пояснить пожалуйста почему параметры передаются как-то через универсальную ссылку? Это как? Они же не тип-они это сразу несколько разных типов? Их же много, да и зачем сама ссылка? Я просто еще не настолько познал шаблоны

Comment: @SupremeMachine 1. `decltype(auto)` - это как `auto`, только работающий по правилам `decltype`. Обычный `auto` никогда не выдает ссылку, и если `bar` сам возвращал бы ссылку, он бы не подошел. А `decltype(auto)` работает как нужно. 2. Нужно передавать по ссылке, потому что `bar` сама может принимать аргументы по ссылке. Если в `foo` принимать по значению, то поведение будет неправильное, если `bar` присвоит что-то ссылке, и т.п. 3. `...` - гуглить по слову "parameter pack".

Comment: А такое возможно организовать не только шаблонами,которые автоматизируют создание перегруженных функций,но и с помощью классических штук, например через указатель на функцию? Или никак не обойтись без магии шаблонов и кучи различных вариантов одной функции скрытых под ними?

Comment: @SupremeMachine Допустим можно, но мне непонятно, какую проблему вы решаете.

Comment: проблема : класс должен уметь своей функцией(методом) вызывать любую другую функцию с любыми(но такими же)  параметрами что она требует. И желательно без многочисленных перегрузок функции из-за магии шаблонов, а реальная цель очень проста: приспичило)

Comment: @SupremeMachine Зачем приспичило? Чем плохи шаблоны? Это [ошибка XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/215103).

Comment: Ну тут согласен,надо было уточнить(уже сделал). А про шаблоны: ну функция из-за них будет реально несколько раз продублирована в памяти с малейшими изменениями рад привязки к ней любой другой. Поэтому и спрашивал,а можно ли на указателях на функцию накрутить подобного?

Comment: @SupremeMachine А вы проверяли, что она будет продублирована?

Comment: @SupremeMachine Почему-то никто никогда не понимает эту ссылку. Расскажите, что именно вы делаете. Зачем вам другое имя для функции, еще и в классе? Возможно мы предложим вариант получше.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144473/discussion-between-supreme-machine-and-holyblackcat).